# Connecting file to phpMyAdmin error

Tags: php, html, css

This problem I am having trouble with, I have been looking at it for a few hours now. So basically I am working on a registration form on my website, and while working on the php, I connected it to MySQL and Database with this line of code (which is the 6th line of code):

> $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost:8080', 'root', 'mypass123', 'accounts');

I use Xampp on a Mac and when I try to register it works just not fully so, the problem is it shows this error:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /opt/lampp/htdocs/form.php on line 6

if this is not enough information, I am sorry but I am new.

Comment: Is the code, which you posted, on line 6? So, is that the part of your code, which gives the error?

Comment: Yes. Since I was trying to connect it but It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP` expects to use port `3306` for `MySQL`. So you need to open XAMPP, and change the XAMPP MySQL port to 3306, then restart the MySQL server.

Comment: How do I exactly do that? Because when I open XAMPP start running it, then go to services and press on mySQL I can't edit it. Or are you talking about the localhost in network because I am able to edit that.

Comment: you can check this article: https://phpmysqllearners.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/changing-phpxampp-port-number-in-xampp/

Answer (score 0):

Stop Xampp

Open xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini

Edit MySQL port to 3306

Restart Xampp

I'd say that it's already set to 3306 so just check what it's currently set to and update the setting in your PHP/phpMyAdmin to 3306 instead of 8080. 8080 is generally for the web server.

Comment: there is a problem to that theory. I'm on a Mac, when I got into lampp (the folders name) and then mysql, it only shows a folder thats called scripts with one file in it, and a readme.

Comment: Been like 2 days, still couldn't fix it. I actually came across more problems because it couldn't connect, any help?

Comment: When you configured phpmyadmin to point to your local server, what did you set the port to? It should be 3306 or whatever your mysql server is running on - it won't be the same as your webserver (8080).